# Renaming odom frame on robot_localization

Tags: ros2, odometry, robot-localization, ros-humble

I'm trying to update my robot_localization config, where I want the odom frame to be called 'odom2' (for example) instead of 'odom'.

But the ekf node only seems to work when the odom frame is called 'odom'. With any other value, the ekf node doesn't publish any filtered odometry or tf. Why is this happening?

I'm using ROS 2 Humble.

Answer (score 0):

The EKF node is subscribed to the topic `/odom`, but you can remap the topic when you launch the node by adding the `--rosargs -r <old name>:=<new name>` flags.

For more info, you can read about command line remapping: https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/Node-arguments.html

Comment: I was talking about the frame ID, not topics or parameters. Topic remapping works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide your full EKF config and a sample message from each sensor input? My guess is that you renamed your EKF `odom` frame to `odom2`, but your inputs are still provided in the `odom` frame, and you haven't provided a transform from `odom`->`odom2`, so the EKF doesn't know how to transform the input data into the target `odom2` frame. But without more detail, it's hard to say.